# How do you formulate an equation that require its own result to replace one of its unknown?

Tags: recursion

Is the concept of recursion used in Mathematics as it is in computer science? How would you express it in a formula?

Comment: For instance:  $f(f(x))$.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve recursive relations?

Comment: He's asking how to *express* recursion in mathematics.

Comment: Isn't $f(f(\ldots f(x)\ldots))$ usually called a *recurrence?*

Comment: @Justpassingby I'd call *that* an iteration

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation would be my reference suggestion here for how to express it as it is used in sequences regularly.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of CS recursion in mathematical logic is induction: if a family of well-formed statements is indexed by the natural numbers, and the first statement is provable, and the $n$-th statement is deducible from the $(n-1)$-th statement, then the statement $\forall n S(n)$ is provable.

Following the above comments I have to add that there is also the notion of a *recurrence relation.* It is a definition of a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ by providing an explicit formula that expresses $f(n)$ in terms of $f(n-1)$ (or in terms of several preceding values, which can be reduced to the original case by a few formal tricks). "Solving" the recurrence then means finding an explicit expression for $f(n)$ that no longer refers to other values of $f.$

Answer (score 1):

Definition by recursion lets you define functions on $\Bbb N$ in terms of other functions:

> Given a set $X$, $n\in\Bbb N$, a function $g\colon X^n\to X$, and another function $h\colon \Bbb N \times X\times X^{n+1}\to X$, there is a unique function $f\colon X^{n+1}\to X$ such that:
>   $$\begin{align}
> f(0, \vec{x}) &= g(\vec{x}), \\
> f(n+1, \vec{x}) &= h(n, f(n), \vec{x})
> \end{align}$$
>   where $\vec{x}\in X^n$.

By induction, any function $f$ satisfying the conclusion is unique. Existence follows from the axioms of set theory.

It's possible to state the principle of definition by recursion more generally — for any well-ordered set, not just $\Bbb N$, an analogous statement is true.